# Declare types for module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have three files:

```js
//some-class.js
class SomeClass {}
module.exports = SomeClass
//helpers.js
const someFunc = () => {}
module.exports = {someFunc}
//index.js
const SomeClass = require("./src/some-class")
const helpers = require("./src/helpers")
module.exports = {SomeClass, helpers}
```

I need to describe types for them, so I`ve created index.d.ts:

```
declare module someModule {
 class SomeClass {}
}
export = someModule
```

But problem with declaring types for `helpers`, what is the better way to do it?

Comment: What's the problem with declaring `helpers` right next to that `class SomeClass`? What syntax did you try that caused an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with namespace:

```js
declare module someModule {
  class SomeClass {
    constructor(v: string);
    test: (v: string) => void;
  }

  namespace helpers {
    export function someFunction(v: any): Promise<string>;
  }
}

export = logger;
```